# ¿Como ocultar etiqueta? Plotly-Python

Tags: python, plotly

En el siguiente código de python, se genera una imagen. ¿Cómo puedo desactivar el rectangulo con las coordenadas que sale al pasar el mouse por ese punto?

```
# x and y given as array_like objects
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En plotly express tienes que hacer un `fig.update_traces` y añadir los argumentos `hovertemplate=None` y `hoverinfo='skip'`. El ejemplo que te pongo a continuacion genera la grafica y no muestra nada al hacer hover con el raton.

```
import plotly.express as px
x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
fig = px.scatter(df, 'x', 'y')

fig.update_traces(
   hovertemplate=None,
   hoverinfo='skip'
)
fig.show()
```